# Use a user control as a DataTemplate within a WPF application

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I am trying to create a user control within a WPF application that will serve as a `DataTemplate` for a `ListBoxItem`. The user control a grid with 4 `TextBlock`s. This control also contains other shapes and images more for visual aid than anything so I am omitting them from the code in this question for clarity.

When I drop the user control on my mainwindow.xaml I can see the control and the properly bound fields point to the first record in the datasource. What I want to do is have this control render repeatedly  within either a listbox or a wrap panel for each record within the database.

Can anyone provide me with a pointer or sample of how to have a user control render as a `DataTemplate` within the `ListBox` control/other panel.

Up to this point I have tried the following with no avail:
Thanks in advance for any tips.

```
<!--within Window.Resource -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="myActivity">
        <local:ucActivityItm /> <!--usercontrol -->
</DataTemplate>

<!-- Listbox within the window -->
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource myActivity}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
 <ListBoxItem>
<!-- control also added for testing to ensure it rendered out-->
<local:ucActivityItm />   
</ListBoxItem>        
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That `DataTemplate` isn't actually being assigned to your `ListBox`. There's three ways:

1: Replace the template in the Resources section with

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:ucActivityItm />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

in the `ListBox`.
2: Somewhat related:

```
<ListBox ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myActivity}">
```

3: Set the DataType parameter of the `DataTemplate` above to whatever the content of your `ListBox` is.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myActivity" DataType="{x:Type ...}">
```

I usually just do the first, but any should work.